# jsx with concatenation using es6 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Link to=`job/applications/${obj._id}/detail`>
</Link>
```

What's wrong with above jsx? I got unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{}`, like this:

```
<Link to = {`job/applications/${obj._id}/detail`}> xyz </Link>
```